# Duplicate input when try to write a file

Tags: php

I am trying to create a log file but the file is written twice using the same string. What should I do to avoid this behavior?

```
     $file = 'newfile.txt';
     $current = file_get_contents($file);
     $current = time()."\n";
     file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    /* output
    1471958308
    1471958308
    1471958312
    1471958312
    1471958734
    1471958734
    */
```

Comment: Do you run this file from web? Try to run it from console.

Comment: How is your code triggered?

Comment: try error_log() function instead

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using FILE_APPEND, which will add onto the end of the file whatever is in `$current` you can just do this

```
<?php

$file = 'newfile.txt';
$current = time()."\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Although with your code it did not duplicate data for me as this line

```
 $current = time()."\n";
```

will overwrite whatever you read from the file with this statement

```
$current = file_get_contents($file);
```

anyway

The only way I can get the duplication you say you are getting is if I use a `.=` instead of a `=` in the  `$current .= time()."\n";`

```
$file = 'newfile.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= time()."\n";                   //<- not the .=
file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: How this helps with doubling timestamps?

Comment: Well I dont thing he published the actual code he was using

Comment: With some server settings this can be achieved.

Comment: @u_mulder See my suggestion of the code OP was actually running!

Answer (score 0):

The script I am using right now is:

```
$file = 'newfile.txt';
$current = time()."\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

If I run the file via command line using (lynx -dump http://dev.test/index.php) after this run the cod via browser (chrome) ... this is the output:

```
1472044823
1472044856
1472044856
```

in conclusion when I run the code via chrome...the timestamp is added twice...why?